# Landau Mechanics equation 16.9

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics

I am having trouble deriving the equation 16.9 from Landau's Classical Mechanics book.
This equation is the maximum kinetic energy of a particle if a massive particle with mass $M$ disintegrates into multiple particles.

Massive particle has an internal energy $E_i$ before it disintegrates, and the particle 1 that we want to get maximum kinetic energy of has an internal energy $E_{1i}$. A system consisted of all the particles except the particle 1 has an internal energy of $E_i'$.

He says the equation
$E_i = E_{1i} + p_0^2/2m_1 + E_{2i} + p_0^2 / 2m_2$ in the case of two particles imply that kinetic energy of the particle 1 is
$(M-m_1)(E_i - E_{1i} - E_i')/M$, which I cannot seem to get.

If I assume that such equation is correct, then I get that sum of kinetic energy of the other particles is $m_1 (E_i - E_{1i} - E_i')/M$, which I do not think is true.

Can anyone help? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reasoning is the same as the two-particle system:
$$
E_i = E_{1i} + \frac{p_0^2}{2m_1} + E_i' + \frac{p_0^2}{2(M-m_1)},
$$
so that
$$
E_i - E_{1i} - E_i' = \frac{p_0^2}{2}\left(\frac{1}{m_1} + \frac{1}{M-m_1}\right)
= \frac{p_0^2}{2}\frac{M}{m_1(M-m_1)}.
$$
Therefore
$$
\frac{p_0^2}{2m_1} = \frac{M-m_1}{M}(E_i - E_{1i} - E_i').
$$