# Landau/Lifshitz "Mechanics" Particle Disintegration

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, collision

I have attempted to derive Eq. (16.9) in Landau/Lishitz' "Mechanics", 3e. If someone could let me know if my derivation is on the right track, it would be greatly appreciated. I do hope that this question won't be closed as a "check-my-work" question, as L+L are notorious for sweeping details under the rug, but I understand if this is the case.

L+L consider the disintegration of a primary particle (mass $M$) into many constituent parts. They derive the following formula for the kinetic energy $T_{10}$ (subscript 0 refers to the centre-of-mass frame) of some secondary particle (mass $m_1$). See [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/141857/landau-mechanics-equation-16-9) for the derivation:

$$
T_{10}'=\frac{M-m_1}{M}\left(E_i-E_{1i}'-E_i'\right)\tag{*}
$$

where $E_i$ is the internal energy of the primary particle, $E_{1i}$ is the internal energy of $m_1$, and $E_{i}'$ is the internal energy of the system formed by every particle except $m_1$. Primes are use to denote that values of quantities after the disintegration. L+L then proceed to derive an upper bound on $T_{10}'$. They note that the maximum of $T_{10}'$ occurs when $E_{i}'$ is minimized. Very well. They then claim that for $E_{i}'$ to be minimized, every secondary particle other than $m_1$ must travel at the same velocity.

To show this, I first consider the law of conservation of momentum in the COM frame:

$$
\underbrace{m_1\vec{v}_{10}'}_{\vec{p}_{10}'}+\underbrace{\sum_{a>1}m_a\vec{v}_{a0}'}_{\vec{P}'}=0
$$

where $a$ enumerates the particles. Whatever the values of $\{v_{a0}'\}$ may be, I know that $\vec{p}_{10}'=p_{10}'\hat{e}$ and $\vec{P}'=-P'\hat{e}$, where $\hat{e}$ is some unit vector; i.e. the momenta are colinear and oppositely-directed in the COM frame. Conserved of momentum can therefore be phrased as

$$
\left(m_1v_{10}'-\Big|\sum_{a>1}m_a\vec{v}_{a0}'\Big|\right)\hat{e}=0
\implies
m_1v_{10}'-\Big|\sum_{a>1}m_a\vec{v}_{a0}'\Big|=0
$$

where I have assumed that $\hat{e}$ is not the zero vector. Next, I thought I should minimize $E_{i}'$ subject to the constraint of momentum conservation. I therefore introduce

$$
f=\underbrace{\sum_{a>1}\left(\frac12\,m_av_{a0}'^2+E_{ai}'\right)}_{E_i'}-\lambda\left(m_1v_{10}'-\Big|\sum_{a>1}m_a\vec{v}_{a0}'\Big|\right)
$$

where $\lambda$ is a Lagrange multiplier. I assume $v_{10}'$ is known and held constant. Taking the gradient of $f$ and equating it to zero, I arrive at the following system of equations

$$
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial f}{\partial \vec{v}_{a0}'}
&=m_a \vec{v}_{a0}'-\lambda m_a \frac{\sum_{a>1}m_a\vec{v}_{a0}'}{\Big|\sum_{a>1}m_a\vec{v}_{a0}'\Big|}=0\tag{1}\\\\
\frac{\partial f}{\partial\lambda}
&=m_1v_{10}'-\Big|\sum_{a>1}m_a\vec{v}_{a0}'\Big|=0\tag{2}
\end{align}
$$

Moving the second term on the left-hand side of (1) to the right, and taking the norm of both sides, I find

$$
\begin{equation}
\lambda=v_{a0}'\tag{3}
\end{equation}
$$

On the other hand, summing both sides over all $a>1$ give me

$$
\sum_{a>1}m_a\vec{v}_{a0}'\left(1-\lambda\,\frac{\sum_{a>1}m_a}{\Big|\sum_{a>1}m_a\vec{v}_{a0}'\Big|}\right)=0
$$

I assume $\sum_{a>1}m_a\vec{v}_{a0}'\ne 0$ (which is consistent with assuming $\hat{e}\ne0$, as above). The term in the round brackets above must therefore vanish. In the numerator, $\sum_{a>1}m_a=M-m_1$. And by (2), the denominator is simply $m_1v_{10}'$. Thus $\lambda$ is determined in terms of $M$ and the mass/velocity of particle 1:

$$
\begin{equation}
\lambda=\frac{m_1v_{10}'}{M-m_1}\tag{4}
\end{equation}
$$

Taken together, Eqs. (3) and (4) imply

$$
v_{a0}'=\lambda=\frac{m_1v_{10}'}{M-m_1}\quad\forall a>1\tag{**}
$$

These $\{v_{a0}'\}$ are equal to some constant independent of $a$ for all $a>1$, as L+L suggest. L+L then claim that, with these velocities, $E_{i}'$ is simply equal to the sum of the binding energies $\{E_{ai}'\}$. Substituting $(**)$ into $E_i'$, I find

$$
E_{i}'=\sum_{a>1}E_{ai}'+(\lambda-\mbox{dependent constant})
$$

which is equal to the sum of the binding energies if the constant term is chosen as the zero of energy.